# sparqle query for capitols of all US's states

Tags: sparql

I am trying to make a sparqle query for the capitols of all US's states. What is wrong with my sparqle query? It keeps failing.

```
# Find US states, their capitals and largest cities
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbpr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbpo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

#for all the capitols in the states
SELECT ?capitol
WHERE {
?capitol dbpo:state ?country .
{ ?capitol a dbpo:capitol } .
{ ?country a dbpprop:country "U.S." } .
}
```

Comment: "It keeps failing" - how, exactly? Do you get an error, or an otherwise unexpected result? Also: where/how are you executing this query? Are you using the public DBPedia endpoint, or something else? Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22753222/edit) to add relevant details.

Comment: Most likely this line: `{ ?country a dbpprop:country "U.S." } .` is the problem. That string "U.S." is not in a syntactically legal spot. I assume that whatever query engine you used gave you an error that specified this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query isn't legal.  If you paste it into [sparql.org's query validator](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html), you'll see the syntax error:

> Input:
>
> ```
>   1 # Find US states, their capitals and largest cities
>   2 PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
>   3 PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
>   4 PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
>   5 PREFIX dbpr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
>   6 PREFIX dbpo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
>   7 PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
>   8 
>   9 #for all the capitols in the states
>  10 SELECT ?capitol
>  11 WHERE {
>  12 ?capitol dbpo:state ?country .
>  13 { ?capitol a dbpo:capitol } .
>  14 { ?country a dbpprop:country "U.S." } .
>  15 }
> ```
>
> Syntax error:
>
> ```
> Encountered "  "\"U.S.\" "" at line 14, column 30.
> Was expecting one of:
>     "values" ...
>     "graph" ...
>     "optional" ...
>     "minus" ...
>     "bind" ...
>     "service" ...
>     "filter" ...
>     "{" ...
>     "}" ...
>     ";" ...
>     "," ...
>     "." ...
> ```

It looks like you're using DBpedia, and if that's the case, then you can this a query like this at the [DBpedia public endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql).  (The variable `?state` is a bit of a misnomer;  there are 56 results.)

```
select ?state ?capital where { 
  ?state dbpedia-owl:capital ?capital ;
         dbpedia-owl:country dbpedia:United_States .
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?state%20?capital%20where%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20?state%20dbpedia-owl%3acapital%20?capital%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl%3acountry%20dbpedia%3aUnited_States%20.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aorder%20by%20?state&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)